# Integrating dynatrace davis ai with microsoft teams

Tags: microsoft-teams, dynatrace

Has anyone integrated dynatrace davis ai with microsoft teams, I was trying to do a webhook but it seems I'd have to write a custom connector

Comment: We do not have Dynatrace davis ai connector inside teams. You can build your [own custom connector](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/webhooks-and-connectors/how-to/connectors-creating).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes you can, see https://www.dynatrace.com/support/help/how-to-use-dynatrace/davis-assistant/integrations/enable-the-davis-assistant-ms-teams-app/ for details.